# Class sfDoctrineRouteCollection not found

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, sfdoctrineguard

I'm starting a new project using SF 1.4.18 and sfDoctrine & sfDoctrineGuard plugins. I had both active at config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php as follow:

```
public function setup() {
    $this->enablePlugins(
            array(
                'sfDoctrinePlugin',
                'sfDoctrineGuardPlugin'
            )
    );
}
```

All is good so far but when I try to reach the URL http://inventario.devserver/backend_dev.php/sfGuardUser this error come up:

> Fatal error: Class 'sfDoctrineRouteCollection' not found in /var/www/html/inventario
>   /plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/lib/routing/sfGuardRouting.class.php on line 59

I don't know what's causing the error because I follow every step at plugins docs. Any help or advice?

Comment: First, if you start a new project with Symfony, you should use the 2.x branch instead of the 1.x. Then, have you cleaned your cache (`php symfony cc`)?

Comment: @j0k Hi I've used Symfony 1.4.18 because hosting doesn't allow Sf 2 due to version of PHP which is 5.1 and Sf2 requires 5.3.x ;) and yes I clean the cache several times (10 or more) but the problem persists

Comment: What do you have in your `/plugins` dir ?

Comment: @j0k This plugins: `sfAdminThemejRollerPlugin, sfDoctrinePlugin, sfDoctrineGuardPlugin, sfFormExtraPlugin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony 1.4 [is shipped with sfDoctrinePlugin](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins). You shouldn't add the plugin on your own.

Remove the folder `sfDoctrinePlugin` from your `/plugins` folder, clear your cache and it will solve your issue.

It's exactly the same problem [from this guy](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/81639/), on the official Symfony forum, in 2009.

Comment: OK, I figure out how to clean the cache (by hand and deleting every inside /cache folder) but now this other error comes up `Fatal error: Class 'sfGuardUserFormFilter' not found in /var/www/html/inventario/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/generator/sfModelGeneratorConfiguration.class.php on line 496`